# Discuss [kafka-cluster -> apache-kafka] synonym approval

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Last week I created a synonym suggestion [kafka-cluster (43) -> apache-kafka (27500)] after reviewing the usage of the kafka-cluster tag, but still no votes as of now.

The reasons I've created the synonym suggestion:

1. 90%+ of the posts tagged with kafka-cluster also have the apache-kafka tag
2. The tag itself doesn't seem to add any value or narrow the scope when used in conjunction with the apache-kafka other than suggesting it's an operational issue with a [Kafka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Kafka) cluster.
3. There's a high correlation between the usage of the kafka-cluster tag and posts related to Kafka server deployment, incident recovery, management operations, and configurations. Most aren't related to any software development at all.